# Determining an IID random process with specifically specified sequences

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am considering the discrete-time discrete-valued random process $X_n$ that consists of the sequences

```
Sequence1:   0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
Sequence2:   1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
Sequence3:   0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
```

with each sequence being chosen with equal probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

After determining that this process is not an i.i.d. random process, I am having trouble finding the joint PMF of $X_{n_1}$ and $X_{n_2}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: The random variables are identically distributed as _Bernoulli_ random variables with parameter $\frac{1}{3}$, but wouldn't you say that $X_n$ and $X_{n+3}$ are _equal_ (with probability $1$ if you like) and so are **not independent**?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I see, what then would be a way to find the PMF of $X_n$?

Comment: >what then would be a way to find the PMF of $X_n$?  The PMF of $X_n$ was _specified_ completely in the first sentence of my previous comment, but to cross the $i$'s and dot the $t$'s $$p_{X_n}(0) = \frac{2}{3}, ~~ p_{X_n}(1) = \frac{1}{3} ~~ \text{for all} ~ n$$ can be obtained  _by inspection_.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oh okay, I believe I am now beginning to understand the idea of describing the PMF of a random process. But for the joint PMF, we would have to consider the certain repetitiveness of the sequence then?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258588.